# Can virtual particles interact with each other?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, vacuum, interactions, virtual-particles

[Virtual particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_particle) pop in and out of existence all the time.
While they exist, can they interact with each other? Like repel or attract one another?

Comment: The first paragraph of the Wikipedia page says that virtual particles are from quantum field theory, where they are represented by the internal lines of Feynman diagrams. Thus virtual particles are just mathematical artifacts due to the perturbative expansion we use. Nevertheless, internal lines of Feynman diagrams can be linked by vertices, in this sense, it is an "interaction between virtual particles".

Comment: This site has lots of questions and answers about virtual particles, and reading some of them should probably answer your question. [Here's a list](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22virtual+particles%22+is%3Aquestion+votes%3A5..) that I got by searching for "virtual particles" questions with 5 or more upvotes. To get this list, I typed `"virtual particles" is:question votes:5..` in the search-box at the top of the Physics SE home page. I even wrote another answer [yesterday](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/619161) that reviews where the "virtual particle" language comes from.

Comment: Yes they can; of course.