# What justifies the interpretation of Feynman Diagrams of physical processes?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory, wick-theorem

Feynman diagrams arise mathematically essentially as neat graphical ways of organising the terms in Wick's theorem for time-ordering. But at the same time we're supposed to interpret them as some sort of "physical process". Like nucleons "exchanging" a meson and so on. But why should the neat mathematical tool have anything to do with what's happening in reality? All they are is a way of doing perturbation theory with pictures instead of integrals. So why should they have physical interpretation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [On the interpretation of Feynman diagrams](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/619123/)

Comment: Physical theories are justified by experiments. Feynman diagrams are part of a theory. Theories are not real, although they may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has a false premise. Nothing justifies Feynman Diagrams as being a physical process, for the reasons you describe. They are just a way of calculating the probability amplitude. It is even known that adding all Feynman diagrams leads to an infinite result. In theories such as Lattice QCD, a nonperturbative approach is taken, and there aren’t diagrams.